# Is down-dll safe?

Tags: security

I needed a specific DLL today that goes by the name libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll. The first Google result was to a site called [down-dll.com](http://down-dll.com/)

Is the site considered a relatively safe site (meaning, assuming there is a safe version of libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll out there somewhere, is the version offered by down-dll.com likely to be safe)?

Comment: As a side note, by I already downloaded it from MinGW directly, but the download was a bit slow overall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't comment on the contents of the dlls but the site didn't report any errors or warnings using [McAfee SiteAdvisor](http://www.siteadvisor.com/sites/down-dll.com), [Norton Safe Web](http://safeweb.norton.com/report/show?url=down-dll.com) or [Online Link Scan](http://onlinelinkscan.com/)

Answer (score 2):

I am the Web Master of [www.down-dll.com](http://www.down-dll.com) and I do take care of passing each single file I put online through [VirusTotal](http://www.virustotal.com/) scan.

Files that don't pass the scan test (mean, none of the virus search engine detect the file as dangerous) I DO NOT put them online and point to a online resource explaining how to check/clean your PC.